# Linking a Shared Library Autotools

Tags: linker, autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm an autotools beginner, and I can't seem to figure out how to use an external library correctly with autotools.

Here is my directory hierarchy.

```
.
├── configure.ac
├── Makefile.am
├── README
└── src
    (source files)
    └── Makefile.am
```

The library's name is `acml_mp` and is, by default, installed in `/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/lib`. There is also a directory called `/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64/include` to include. When I compile without autotools, including the usual compiler flags works fine:

```
g++ ... -L/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64_mp/lib -I/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64_mp/include -lacml_mp ...
```

In configure.ac, I put the command `AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS([acml_mp])` which I think only deals with the `-lacml_mp` flag.

Basically, the end goal is to have autoconf search for this library, and have the makefile generated by automake include the correct link/include paths when compiling. Finally, when compiling by hand, I always need to modify the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using the command

```
Export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran64_mp/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

which, ideally, I would like to avoid having the user do. Apologies if this information exists already, I looked through SO and Google for a few hours to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with searching is that `/opt/acml5.3.1/gfortran` is never going to be a standard (search) location for libraries (and headers) like `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` etc. Probably the best bet is to supply this location explicitly via `--with-acml` to configure.

The `AC_ARG_WITH` macro is described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#External-Software). Assuming `test "x$with_acml" != xno`, you can try linking a program with [`AC_LINK_IFELSE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Running-the-Linker).

```
AC_LANG_PUSH([C]) # or [Fortran]

ac_save_acml_CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS" # or FCFLAGS instead of CPPFLAGS.
ac_save_acml_LIBS="$LIBS"

ac_acml_CPPFLAGS="-I${with_acml}/include"
ac_acml_LIBS="-L${with_acml}/libs -lacml_mp"

CPPFLAGS+="$ac_acml_CPPFLAGS"
LIBS+="$ac_acml_LIBS"

AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM( ... some C or Fortran program ... )],,
               AC_MSG_FAILURE([couldn't link with acml]))

AC_LANG_POP

# we *could* stop here... but we might need the original values later.

CPPFLAGS="$ac_save_acml_CPPFLAGS"
LIBS="$ac_save_acml_LIBS"

AC_SUBST(ACML_CPPFLAGS, $ac_acml_CPPFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(ACML_LIBFLAGS, $ac_acml_LIBS)
```

Assuming you've initialized libtool support with [`LT_INIT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#LT_005fINIT), you can add the acml library with `$(ACML_LIBFLAGS)` to your own libraries in `src/Makefile.am` via the `LIBADD` variable, or to executables with the `LDADD` variable. or `<lib>_la_LIBADD`, `<prog>_LDADD` respectively.

To compile sources with the `$(ACML_CPPFLAGS)` include path, add it to the `AM_CPPFLAGS` variable. Or the `<prog>_CPPFLAGS` variable.

It's difficult to be specific without knowing how your `Makefile.am` is already set up. I know it looks complicated - but it's better to get the infrastructure right the first time. I'll add to the answer if you have further questions.